# Software to record lectures with powerpoint, web cam video, and mic audio

Tags: powerpoint, video-recording

I'm looking for a software that can help record a video lecture with the following requirements:

1. Record a **Powerpoint** slide ***in slide show mode*** (because the pen functionality will be used to write things on the slide as well in slide show mode). We already have a Wacom tablet to write on and it works fine with Powerpoint presentations, but we need to be able to record in presentation mode.
2. Record a **video** of the lecturer's face (with the laptop's webcam) while he/she is speaking and writing on the presentation slide.
3. The video needs to show up in a rectangular box in a corner of the presentation, say, the bottom right.
4. **Audio** for the video needs to come from a bluetooth mic input.
5. Needs to work on **Windows** (any version).
6. **Minimal editing**. While it is possible to record the screen and the video separately and merge the two with video editing software, I'd prefer a software that can record the entire lecture with PPT and video rather than having to merge and synchronize. Editing would be a last resort.

Price isn't a concern, but the software needs to satisfy the requirements.

I have searched for software myself, as well as on this site, but I haven't found one that can display the web cam video 'above' the Powerpoint presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, within half an hour of posting this question, I have the perfect solution.

**OBS Studio**. It is used to record gaming videos. It can be downloaded [here](https://www.twitch.tv/broadcast?no-mobile-redirect=true) (it is the first link on the page).

And, it is free and open source!

I recorded a sample so I can confirm it meets all the requirements above.